# Python Check for decimals

Tags: python

i'm making a program which divides a lot of numbers and I want to check if the number gets decimals or not. I also want it to print those decimals. Example:

```
foo = 7/3
if foo has a 3 in the decimals: # (Just an example of what I want to do there)
    print("It works!")
elif foo has no decimals: # (another example)
    print("It has no decimals")
```

EDIT: Ok, so since "check which decimal is afterwards" brought some confusion, let me explain. I want to be able to check IF a number has decimals. For example, 7/3 (foo) gives me decimals, but I want python to tell me that without me having to do the math. forget the "which decimal" part

Comment: what is your specific question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test whether a division has decimals, just check the modulo:

```
foo = a % b
if foo != 0:
    # Then foo contains decimals
    pass

if foo == 0:
    # Then foo does NOT contain decimals
    pass
```

However (since your question is a bit unclear) if you want to split the integer and decimal parts then use [`math.modf()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf) function:

```
import math
x = 1234.5678
math.modf(x) # (0.5678000000000338, 1234.0)
```

Comment: `if foo == 0 : #FOO DOES NOT CONTAIN DECIMALS` ... other than that a%b is definately the best way to check **if** the result has some decimals ... and modf is great to check if an arbitrary number has a decimal portion

Answer (score 2):

In python you have the int() function that has the ability to turn any float number to a integer.

Example:

```
x = 53.980   
print(int(x))# 53
```

So if after that conversion you check if the float number is different from the converted integer number you will know if after the decimal point there are any numbers.

So 53.056 would return True while 53.000 or 53 would return False
Notice the bellow function putting this in practice

```
def check_decimals(x):
    if x != int(x):
        print(f"Has decimal numbers")
    else:
        print(f"Does not have decimal numbers")

a = 53.06
check_decimals(a)# Has decimal numbers

b = 53.00
check_decimals(b)# Does not have decimal numbers

c = 53
check_decimals(c)# Does not have decimal numbers
```

So if this is what you need you can simply forget the function and do an inline statement like so:

```
    a = 53.06
    print(a != int(a))# True  'Has decimal numbers'
    print(a == int(a))# False 'Does not have decimal numbers'
```

If in other hand you want to find out if a number has a decimal point, you can check if it is a floating point number using the isinstance method:

```
a = 53.00
print(isinstance(a,float))# True
print(isinstance(a,int))# False
b = 53
print(isinstance(b,float))# False
print(isinstance(b,int))# True
```

Comment: Technically, 53.00 is represented as a float and the output should be "Has decimal numbers".

Comment: My application is ensuring that no rounding occurs when converting to int, so `if a != int(a)` was good for my context. +1

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wording of your question I am assuming that you are looking to see if a certain number comes after the decimal point? If that is the case...

What you can do is split foo using `.` as the delimiter and check to see if the number, in this case you're looking for 3, is in portion after the `.`

```
foo = 7/float(3)
foo = str(foo)
after_decimal = foo.split('.')[1]
if '3' in after_decimal:
    print 'Yes!'
else:
    print 'No!'

In this case the output is: Yes!
```

Comment: It tells me that 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @AndreasSandberg I updated it. Try it again with the new code :)

Comment: @Harrison Your code is not Pythonic at all, `math.modf()` function is way better for the job.

Comment: lol how do you check if 3 is in the decimal portion in your version @RyanB. .. I think this answer is pretty dang reasonable ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Check his updated question, he just wants to know _if_ it contains decimals.

Comment: @RyanB. I realize this is not the most efficient option, but it's entirely functional.

Comment: @RyanB. I was assuming that because in his question he is talking about checking if there is a 3 in the decimals that he wants to be able to check if a certain number lies within the decimal places in a number.

Comment: ok so he reworded it ... but it sounded like he wanted to check for a specific digit in the initial question ... based on the initial question this answer is plenty good(perhaps best) ... based on the updated question your solution is definately better

Answer (score 0):

your question is slightly unclear. However this bit of code might get you in the right direction. Just call `Decimal_Checker` and input the numbers you want.

```
def Decimal_Checker(x,y):
    if x %y != 0:
        print("it has decimals")
    else:
        print("it does not have decimals")

Decimal_Checker(3,2)
```

Comment: also acceptable imho ... especially since it is not very clear what the op actually wants?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to detect the decimal, you might code this way.

```
str_foo = str(foo) #Makes foo a string.
if "." in str_foo: #Checks if foo is a decimal.
    print("The following has decimal.")
elif "." not in str_foo: #Checks if foo is not a decimal.
    print("The following doesn't have decimal.")
else:
    pass #Pass does nothing, but I prefer adding it because I want it look less confusing.
```

Or you can import decimal checker.

```
import decimal #Imports decimal from library.
if foo == decimal.detect(".") #Checks if the decimal point exist.
    print("foo is a decimal.")
```

I recommend you using the first code, because the second code only works in `Python2`.
But it will still work if you download `Python2`, the unsupported version.
If you have any more questions, ask me in comment.